# how do I use OR operator in regular expression for sql

Tags: sql

I've having problem with using OR operator in regular expression for updating the multiple set for email that doesn't work at all. I'm trying to update from:

```
 alisonsmith@gmail.com
 bobgraves@hotmail.com
 smithers@yahoo.com 
 011013092949@bony.com
 james@bony.com

 result should look like this:

 alisonsmith@dony.com
 bobgraves@dony.com
 smithers@dony.com
 011013092949@bony.com
 james@bony.com


 I've tried that update procedure for using OR operator like this and it didn't work at all:

 update dbo.Membership   
set Email = left(Email, charindex('@', Email, 0)) + 'dony.com'
OR Email= left(Email, charindex('@', Email, 0)) + 'bony.com';
```

Comment: you only want to update the addresses that don't contain "bony.com" to substitute "dony" for @*.com?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?:

```
update dbo.Membership   
set Email = left(Email, charindex('@', Email, 0)) + 'dony.com'
WHERE Email NOT LIKE '%@bony.com'
```